# XSLT - Get specific value from external XML document

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to get a specific value if a condition is satisfied. The way to get this is by doing a look up for a specific value from the original xml document and compare it to an external one.

```
<xsl:variable name="objNo">
    <!-- If True, look up in document and get 'obj' -->
    <xsl:when test="cac:AdditionalDocumentReference[cbc:DocumentType = 'AKV']">
        <xsl:variable name='QueryResult' select='document("tmp9501.xml")/QueryResult/Result'/>
        <xsl:value-of select='$QueryResult[ac_name = cac:AdditionalDocumentReference/cbc:ID]/obj'/>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:variable>
```

This is part of the tmp9501.xml document where I will look for values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<QueryResult>
    <Result>
        <ac_name>12345678</ac_name>
        <obj>AA12345</obj>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <ac_name>87654321</ac_name>
        <obj>BB67890</obj>
    </Result>
</QueryResult>
```

When I try to run this code $regNo returns nothing.

Let's assume that `cac:AdditionalDocumentReference/cbc:ID = 12345678` which should return `obj = AA12345`
How can I in this case return the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this expression....

```
$QueryResult[ac_name = cac:AdditionalDocumentReference/cbc:ID]
```

This is looking for an `ac_name` under the `QueryResult/Result` nodes, as well as a `cac:AdditionalDocumentReference` under the same `QueryResult/Result`, when really you want to be checking for the `cac:AdditionalDocumentReference` under the current node.

```
<xsl:value-of select='$QueryResult[ac_name = current()/cac:AdditionalDocumentReference/cbc:ID]/obj'/>
```

Alternatively, store the relevant value in a variable before hand....

```
<xsl:variable name="id" select="cac:AdditionalDocumentReference/cbc:ID" />
<xsl:value-of select='$QueryResult[ac_name = $id]/obj'/>
```